# Plant disease identification

Tags: species-identification

I’ve noticed recently strange formations on the leaves of my flower.
No idea what could it be.

Could anyone help with the identification? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white things look like scale insects, you can scrape them (and their waxy fluffy coats) off the leaves.

If you can identify the plant, that would also help.
The gardening SE is also a good place for these questions.

Comment: For the limited amount you have it will be much more effective to scrape them off than try to poison them.